# How to place figure in the absolute top position?

Tags: floats, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I'm using IEEE conference style `spconf.sty`

My question is, how to place a figure in the absolute top position in a page, and leaving no space on the top or left or right.

For example, the figure below:

the red area is the original figure.

How do I span it to blue area? Or green area?
[image]

The current code for the figure is:

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{figures/aaa}
 \caption{aaa}
 \label{aaa}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: If this is for a conference, don't do it.  They may decide to add a header.  If not, you can use `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\vskip*{\dimexpr -1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep}...}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is for conference, but they wont't add anything in the header, so it is okay. Where should I insert this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a slight gap left.  It is smaller than `\topskip` or `\dblfloatsep` or `\dbltextfloatsep`, so it probably isn't deliberate.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[tp]% AFAICT, adding ! does nothing useful
 \vspace*{\dimexpr -1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep}%
 \makebox[\textwidth]{%
   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}
 \caption{aaa}% do not put inside \makebox
 \label{aaa}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really thanks, this could work.. BTW, how to make it to show on the bottom of the page?

Comment: The dblfloatfix package will enable [b].  You will also have to move the \vspace to the bottom of the figure* environment.